# Polling with deltas vs Sockets

Tags: rest, express, backend

**Background**

- I have a todo-style web app, which relies on semi-live task fetching
- My backend is written as a RESTful api, so I thought a poll-like implementation with a delta would be most natural

**Data & Users**

- My target audience is about 2k live users at a time
- The task list would change at most once every 10-20 minutes for an average user
- The frontend should know about the change at most 5 seconds after it happens
- Tasks have very small payload size

**Technology**

PostgreSQL, Express

**Question**

Taking this information into account, would polling be an efficient-enough solution or should I consider spending time on a socket implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the front-end has to know about a change within 5 seconds, polling is going to be hugely inefficient.  With 2k live users and a polling interval of say 3 seconds to make sure you get the response and display it within 5 seconds of when it happens, then you're going to have 2000 requests every 3 seconds, 24 hours a day that are just asking if there's anything new.  While that's doable ~700 requests/sec just for polling, it's a huge waste of server cycles and unless you had a cluster, you'd have to make sure you could handle each request in less than 1.5ms just to keep up.

A webSocket or socket.io implementation seems to me like it makes a lot more sense.  Then, all your server has to do when there's nothing new is respond to an occasional keep-alive (which is done at a pretty low level and is very fast).  Plus, when there is something new to send to the clients, it will arrive nearly immediate.  You will have to make sure your hosting package and server are configured properly for 2000 simultaneous webSocket/socket.io connections, but that's very doable with proper configuration since it's really just socket allocations as an inactive, but open socket doesn't use any network or CPU except for a tiny amount of bandwidth for whatever types of keep-alives are configured (way less bandwidth than polling).

Answer (score 0):

Coming back to this question after a few months. I found that leveraging Firebase Cloud Messaging for these kinds of tasks is invaluable for apps with authentication (my use case).

- It has perfect integration with push notifications on mobile phones
- Minimal load on the server
- Minimal authentication logic
- Browser support
- Completely free
- No need to manage an active socket